# Is there a way to create a collection with partitionKey/shardKey in Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo API using Java?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to create a collection with shard key in Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo API, but this code throws an error as `com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: Partition key path /partKey is invalid for MongoDB API.`

```
    public void createCollections(String collectionNames, String dbName, int throughput, String partitionKey) throws DocumentClientException{    
                    DocumentCollection curCol = new DocumentCollection();
                    curCol.setId(collectionNames);
                    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
                    paths.add(partitionKey);
                    PartitionKeyDefinition partDef = new PartitionKeyDefinition();
                    partDef.setPaths(paths);
                    curCol.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
                    RequestOptions reqOp = new RequestOptions();
                    reqOp.setOfferThroughput(throughput);
                    try (DocumentClient db = this.getDocClient(this.getAccountEndPoint(), this.getAccountKey())) {
                        db.createCollection(DBLINK + dbName, curCol, reqOp);
                    }
}
```

Is there is any way to create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK to create a MongoDB resource. That SDK only works with SQL API accounts in Cosmos DB.

To work with MongoDB API resources in Cosmos DB, you need to use native [MongoDB drivers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers). To use these drivers to create and manage MongoDB resources in Cosmos DB you use the [MongoDB extension commands for Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/custom-commands). These provide the options to specify throughput, shard keys, etc.

Here is a Java example to create a collection for the MongoDB API for Cosmos DB. Apologies for poor Java usage, been a while since I wrote any.

```
String uri = "<connection string uri>";
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri) 
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDatabase");

Document doc = new Document("customAction", "CreateCollection")
    .append("collection", "myCollectionName")
    .append("shardKey", "partKey")
    .append("offerThroughput", 400);

Document commandResult = database.runCommand(doc);
System.out.println("dbStats: " + commandResult.toJson());
```